# Get ClassName of a Window from Window Reference

Tags: wpf, window, classname

I have a Window partial class (WPF Window) like:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
   // this is just a WPF window

   // I have in XAML Closing event like Closing="Window_Closing"
   // and here is the event definition
   public void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
   {
      SaveWindowState(this); // just passes reference to itself
   }   
}
```

In another assembly, I have logic which receives reference passed in above like this

```
public static void SaveWindowState(Window window)
{
    // Since I can call this from many windows, I need a way to get
    // the class name of my window in here.  Basically, for MyWindow
    // above, I need to get "MyWindow" and for other windows, I need
    // to get thier class name from the passed in "window" parameter.
}
```

How do I get the actual class name for the passed in Window?

Comment: The bigger question is why you would need a class name passed around. Maybe your are approaching your actual problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `window.GetType().Name`?